# Vue.js Bootstrap table - pass data between Parent and Child component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, bootstrap-vue, bootstrap-table

I have 2 components: Parent and Child. In both components, I'm using Bootstrap tables and their 'items' and 'fields' come from API. The `Child component` should pass data (true or false, for each table row) to the `Parent component`. I want to assign this data from the Child component to the Parent component bootstrap table row object. You can see my code below.

So, the problem is that the `v-if` statement doesn't work. It seems like the object `'state'` is assigned before the component is created because on `console.log` I can see that the new `'state'` object is there and filled correctly with true/false but in DOM the situation is different, the `state` is undefined.

Anyone who can help how can I set the `'state'` object and make it works?

Parent component:

```
<template>
    <b-table v-else :items=“customItems” :fields="fields" responsive>
        <template v-slot:cell(config)="row">
            <child-component
              @onitembind='isSingleRow'>
            </child-component>
        </template>       
    </b-table>
</template>

<!-- Checkbox column --> 
<template v-slot:cell(labelCheckbox)="row">
    <div class="label-checkbox" v-if="row.item.state">
        <span><i class="fa fa-angle-up text-primary">
    </div>
</template>



<script>
    methods: {
        isSingleRow(event) {
            this.singleRow.push(event);
            for(let i in this.customItems){
                this.customItems[i].state = this.singleRow[i]
                console.log('EHO ', i, ' ', this.customItems[i]);
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Child component:

```
<script>
    created() {
            this.tableRowsLength()
    },

    methods: {
        tableRowsLength () {
                if((this.innerTableItems.length) != 1){
                    this.$emit('onitembind', true)
                } else{
                    this.$emit('onitembind', false) 
                 }
            }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Does the `state` property exist prior to you setting it?

Comment: @Hiws no, actually I create it in the method isSingleRow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Vue 2, adding properties to an existing object wont be reactive, as Vue wont be able to properly add a getter/setter for the property.

To get around this you should use the `Vue.set`/`this.$set` method.

`this.$set(this.customItems[i], 'state', this.singleRow[i])`

For more information see: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#For-Objects